# Anaconda Spyder update

Tags: anaconda, spyder, navigator

I am running a freshly downloaded version of ACONDA.NAVIGATOR, v 2.0.1. With the installation also came Spyder, vs. 4.1.5. Whenever I launch Spyder I get a message that a new version 5.0.0 is available, but the instructions one is referred to there do not work. In particular, "conda update spyder" says 'All requested packages already installed'. In the Spyder window in Navigator the 'update application' in the upper right corner is greyed out. The option 'Install specific version' allows only for installation of older versions. What to do now for a Spyder update??

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Those instructions are outdated. Instead, please run `conda update anaconda` and then `conda install spyder=4.2.5`. That should work.

Comment: Please don't update to Spyder 5.0.0 because it has several bugs. Most of them are fixed already in our latest version (5.0.2), but unfortunately Anaconda hasn't uploaded packages for it yet.

Comment: Thanks, that update to 4.2.5 worked.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked for you.